# Hows to deploy .dwp file as a feature in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

I have a .dwp file which I got by exporting my webpart . Now I want to make feature using WSP builder. I knw I have to create element.xml,feature.xml and Webpart1.wepart
but I was going through the method what I didn't get is where to put the .dwp file in 12 hive and also where I will give the location of this .dwp file ? In element.xml i m giving location of Webpart1.wepart then where I m giving location of this .dwp file....

And also where to put the dll file?

Any help would really be appreciated .

Thanks,

Comment: A .dwp is an older version of .webpart. You stick both in the Feature folder. The element.xml decides where it should go, this is no different from the .webpart file either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open up the Web Part Gallery and upload your DWP file there (see info in this tutorial http://www.datasprings.com/Resources/ArticlesInformation/Sharepoint2007CustomWebParts.aspx)

However, as people are stating in other comments, it is generally considered "better" to deploy webparts as features: http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2007/05/deploying-web-parts-as-feature.html

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you are asking for, but this is my guess: you want to disect the .dwp file you got, package it in a solution package containing that feature.

If that's the case, then here are some pointers

1. [Schemas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms414322.aspx) of the various files involved in the process
2. [Some instructions](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/articles/UsingVisualStudioAndMsBuildToCreateWssSolutions.aspx) on how to leverage VS to create a wsp file
3. Once done, you can use stsadm (or powershell) to deploy and install the solution:

SET STSADM="C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\BIN\STSADM.EXE"

SET URL="http://your server"

SET SPACK="thePackage.wsp"

%STSADM% -o retractsolution -name %SPACK% -immediate -url %URL%
%STSADM% -o execadmsvcjobs

%STSADM% -o deletesolution -name %SPACK% -override
%STSADM% -o execadmsvcjobs

%STSADM% -o addsolution -filename %SPACK%
%STSADM% -o execadmsvcjobs

%STSADM% -o deploysolution -name %SPACK% -immediate -allowgacdeployment -url %URL%
%STSADM% -o execadmsvcjobs

I hope this gets closer to what you are asking for.